# Unable to locate package percona-clustercheck

Tags: mysql, percona, xtradb

When i try to remove percona-pxc from my Ubuntu 14.04 using the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove -y percona*
```

I get the following errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package percona-clustercheck
E: Unable to locate package percona-monitoring-plugins-1.1.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'percona-monitoring-plugins-1.1.5'
```

How can i get rid of this error?